# How to display text on a button using JS efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a div when I click on a button and hide the others.

Here's my approach:

```js
var enunt = document.querySelector(".enunt");
var rezolvare = document.querySelector(".rezolvare");
var explicatie = document.querySelector(".explicatie");
var complexitate = document.querySelector(".complexitate");
var executie = document.querySelector(".executie");

var enuntText = document.querySelector(".enunt-problema");
var rezolvareText = document.querySelector(".rezolvare-problema");
var explicatieText = document.querySelector(".explicare-problema");
var complexitateText = document.querySelector(".complexitate-problema");
var executieText = document.querySelector(".executie-problema");

enunt.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "block";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

rezolvare.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "block";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

explicatie.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "block";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

complexitate.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "block";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

executie.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #00000f;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova" !important;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #00000f !important;
}

.navbar-custom {
    position: relative;
}

.abs-center-x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bg-transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.nav-color {
    color :#fff !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}

.nav-color:hover {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.nav-active {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.display-custom {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 17.5rem !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.lead-custom {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

/*Continut centru*/

#central {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
    display: table;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#intro-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 710px;
    width: 100%;
}

#intro {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1 !important;
    font-size: 17.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

#hr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

hr {
    border-color: #77dff1 !important;
    max-width: 90%;
}


.button-wrap {
    postion: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.button-custom {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #77dff1;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-custom:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #00000f;
    background: #77dff1;
}

/* probleme DEI */

.list-item-custom {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item-custom:hover {
    background-color: #77dff1;
    color: #fff;
}

.col-sm-6 {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.col-hover:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    background: #77dff1;
}

.col-custom {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pre-scrollable {
    max-height: 700px !important;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
}

.lista-pasi-executie {
    list-style: decimal;
}

.fontawesome-custom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 20rem;
}

.autor-color {
    color: #77dff1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.explicatie-rezolvare {
    color: #77dff1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lista-observatii {
    list-style: disc;
}

.lista-pasi-executie > li {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.autor-problema-span {
    color: #77dff1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pre-custom {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.fontawesome-custom {
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.autor-problema {
    font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Divide et Impera</title>
    <link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/fonts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6612084f00.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color: #fff !important"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Introducere DEI</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">DEI Iterativ</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color nav-active" href="#">Probleme DEI</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 1%; transform:translateY(-50%);">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom enunt">Enunt</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom rezolvare">Rezolvare + cod</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom explicatie">Explicatie rezolvare</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom complexitate">Complexitate</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom executie">Executie</li>
                  </ul>
          </div>
              <div class="enunt-problema">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard fontawesome-custom"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                      <div class="autor-problema">Autor: <span class="autor-problema-span">Mihai Vasile</span></div>
                        Sa se demonstreze daca un arbore binar este de tipul BST (binary search tree)
                              <div class="observatie-BST">
                                <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #77dff1;">Observatie </span>- un BST are urmatoarele proprietati:
                              </div>
                              <ul class="lista-observatii">
                                <li>Orice subarbore din partea stanga al unui nod contine valori mai mici decat nodul “tata”</li>
                                <li>Orice subarbore din partea dreapta al unui nod contine valori mai mari decat nodul “tata”</li>
                                <li>Atat subarborele drept, cat si cel stang trebuie sa fie la randul lor BST</li>
                              </ul>   
                    </div>
                  </div>                 
              </div>
              <div class="rezolvare-problema" style="display: none;">
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <pre class="pre-scrollable pre-custom">
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

//Un nod al unui arbore binar are drept componente id-ul sau,
//cat si pointeri catre "copilul" drept si cel stang.

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    // Allocam noului nod id-ul sau 
    //si initializam pointeri catre stanga si dreapta cu NULL
    node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
    }
};

int isBSTUtil(node* node, int min, int max);

/* Functia principala ce verifica daca arborele binar
este de tip BST sau nu, utilizand o functie secundara numita
isBSTUtil */
int isBST(node* node)
{
    return(isBSTUtil(node, INT_MIN, INT_MAX));
}
/* Intoarce adevarat daca arborele dat este de tip BST si
se respecta conditiile impuse in cerinta: 
id-ul sa fie >=min si <=max 
*/
int isBSTUtil(node* node, int min, int max)
{
    /* un nod NULL este de tip BST */
    if (node == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* fals daca id-ul nodului nu este cuprins intre min si max */
    if (node->data < min || node->data > max)
        return 0;

    /* Daca nodul curent respecta conditia BST, se verifica recursiv subarbori acestuia,
    modificand corespunzator min si max */
    return
        isBSTUtil(node->left, min, node->data - 1) && // Id-urile nu trebuie sa se repete  
        isBSTUtil(node->right, node->data + 1, max); // Id-urile nu trebuie sa se repete
}


int main()
{
    node* root = new node(4);
    root->left = new node(2);
    root->right = new node(5);
    root->left->left = new node(1);
    root->left->right = new node(3);

    if (isBST(root))
        cout << "Este BST";
    else
        cout << "Nu este BST";

    return 0;
}
                    </pre>
                      </pre>
                  </div>
                </div>                  
              </div>
              <div class="explicare-problema" style="display: none; color: #fff;">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                    <i class="far fa-lightbulb fontawesome-custom"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                      <div class="col-custom" style="text-align: left;">
                        <span class="explicatie-rezolvare">Explicatie rezolvare:</span>  
        Problema are la baza verificarea daca id-urile unice ale unor noduri dintr-un arbore respecta conditiile specifice unui arbore BST.
        Incepem prin a ne declara arborele, acesta fiind o clasa ce contine: id-ul, cat si pointeri catre „fii” (subarborii) sai: stang si drept.
        Se apeleaza functia ce verifica daca arborele este BST sau nu, aceasta efectuand urmatoarele operatii:
        <ol class="lista-pasi-executie">
          <li>Se seteaza initial limitele intre care trebuie sa se situeze nodurile min si max drept limitele tipului de data INT</li>
          <li>Verifica daca nodul dat este NULL, caz in care returnaza adevarat (un nod gol este de tip BST deoarece nu influenteaza min si max si nu are un id asociat)</li>
          <li>Se verifica daca id-ul nodului este cuprins in intervalul [min,max].</li>
          <li>In caz negativ, functia returneaza 0;</li>
          <li>In caz afirmativ, se apeleaza recursiv functia mai intai pe partea stanga a arborelui, dupa care pe partea dreapta, modificand min si max corespunzator directiei in care o luam</li>
        </ol>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>                 
              </div>
              <div class="complexitate-problema" style="display: none; color: #fff;">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-line fontawesome-custom"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                        <span style="color: #77dff1;">Complexitate:</span> O(n) <br>
                        <span style="color: #77dff1;">Demonstratie complexitate:</span><br>
                        Algoritmul prezentat mai sus verifica daca id-ul nodului curent se afla in intervalul [min,max]. In caz afirmativ, acesta se autoapeleaza si continua aceasta verificare a id-ului mai intai in subarborii stangi, dupa care cei drepti.
                        Astfel, pentru un arbore de marime n, sunt parcurse in mod recursiv toate cele n noduri, ceea ce da programului o complexitate medie de O(n).
                    </div>
                  </div>                 
              </div>
            <div class="executie-problema" style="display: none;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                  <i class="fas fa-cogs fontawesome-custom"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really like it because it's not really intuitive. Each time the user clicks on a button, 5 operations have to be done.

I'm pretty sure there is a better approach for this, but I don't know how to do it.

Can anybody help me simplify my JS code and also make it more efficiently?

Comment: Please post RENDERED HTML in a [mcve]. You have dumped all sorts of server code here and a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think I did to be honest. I don't even have server-side code here. I only have JS + the required CSS for the page + HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate

I added a class hide, gave the UL an ID and gave data attributes to the LIs

```js
document.getElementById("listUL").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const id = tgt.dataset.id;
  console.log(id);
  [...document.querySelectorAll("div.problema")]
  .forEach(div => div.classList.toggle("hide", !div.classList.contains(id)))
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 10px;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: #00000f;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova" !important;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #00000f !important;
}

.navbar-custom {
  position: relative;
}

.abs-center-x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bg-transparent {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.nav-color {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
}

.nav-color:hover {
  color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.nav-active {
  color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.display-custom {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #77dff1;
  font-size: 17.5rem !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.lead-custom {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 710px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #eeede7 !important;
}


/*Continut centru*/

#central {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#intro-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 710px;
  width: 100%;
}

#intro {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #77dff1 !important;
  font-size: 17.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 710px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #eeede7 !important;
}

#hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

hr {
  border-color: #77dff1 !important;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.button-wrap {
  postion: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.button-custom {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #77dff1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-custom:hover {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #00000f;
  background: #77dff1;
}


/* probleme DEI */

.list-item-custom {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #77dff1;
  color: #77dff1;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item-custom:hover {
  background-color: #77dff1;
  color: #fff;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #77dff1;
  color: #77dff1;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.col-hover:hover {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  background: #77dff1;
}

.col-custom {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pre-scrollable {
  max-height: 700px !important;
  border: 1px solid #77dff1;
}

.lista-pasi-executie {
  list-style: decimal;
}

.fontawesome-custom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #77dff1;
  font-size: 20rem;
}

.autor-color {
  color: #77dff1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.explicatie-rezolvare {
  color: #77dff1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lista-observatii {
  list-style: disc;
}

.lista-pasi-executie>li {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.autor-problema-span {
  color: #77dff1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pre-custom {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.fontawesome-custom {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.autor-problema {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Divide et Impera</title>
  <link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../css/fonts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6612084f00.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color: #fff !important"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Introducere DEI</a>
          <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">DEI Iterativ</a>
          <a class="nav-link nav-color nav-active" href="#">Probleme DEI</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 1%; transform:translateY(-50%);">
      <ul class="list-group" id="listUL">
        <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom" data-id="enunt">Enunt</li>
        <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom" data-id="rezolvare">Rezolvare + cod</li>
        <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom" data-id="explicatie">Explicatie rezolvare</li>
        <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom" data-id="complexitate">Complexitate</li>
        <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom" data-id="executie">Executie</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="enunt problema hide">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          <i class="fas fa-clipboard fontawesome-custom"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          <div class="autor-problema">Autor: <span class="autor-problema-span">Mihai Vasile</span></div>
          Sa se demonstreze daca un arbore binar este de tipul BST (binary search tree)
          <div class="observatie-BST">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #77dff1;">Observatie </span>- un BST are urmatoarele proprietati:
          </div>
          <ul class="lista-observatii">
            <li>Orice subarbore din partea stanga al unui nod contine valori mai mici decat nodul “tata”</li>
            <li>Orice subarbore din partea dreapta al unui nod contine valori mai mari decat nodul “tata”</li>
            <li>Atat subarborele drept, cat si cel stang trebuie sa fie la randul lor BST</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rezolvare problema hide">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
<h1>REZOLVARE</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="explicare problema hide" style="color: #fff;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          <i class="far fa-lightbulb fontawesome-custom"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          <div class="col-custom" style="text-align: left;">
            <span class="explicatie-rezolvare">Explicatie rezolvare:</span> Problema are la baza verificarea daca id-urile unice ale unor noduri dintr-un arbore respecta conditiile specifice unui arbore BST. Incepem prin a ne declara arborele, acesta
            fiind o clasa ce contine: id-ul, cat si pointeri catre „fii” (subarborii) sai: stang si drept. Se apeleaza functia ce verifica daca arborele este BST sau nu, aceasta efectuand urmatoarele operatii:
            <ol class="lista-pasi-executie">
              <li>Se seteaza initial limitele intre care trebuie sa se situeze nodurile min si max drept limitele tipului de data INT</li>
              <li>Verifica daca nodul dat este NULL, caz in care returnaza adevarat (un nod gol este de tip BST deoarece nu influenteaza min si max si nu are un id asociat)</li>
              <li>Se verifica daca id-ul nodului este cuprins in intervalul [min,max].</li>
              <li>In caz negativ, functia returneaza 0;</li>
              <li>In caz afirmativ, se apeleaza recursiv functia mai intai pe partea stanga a arborelui, dupa care pe partea dreapta, modificand min si max corespunzator directiei in care o luam</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="complexitate problema hide" style="color: #fff;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          <i class="fas fa-chart-line fontawesome-custom"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          <span style="color: #77dff1;">Complexitate:</span> O(n) <br>
          <span style="color: #77dff1;">Demonstratie complexitate:</span><br> Algoritmul prezentat mai sus verifica daca id-ul nodului curent se afla in intervalul [min,max]. In caz afirmativ, acesta se autoapeleaza si continua aceasta verificare a id-ului
          mai intai in subarborii stangi, dupa care cei drepti. Astfel, pentru un arbore de marime n, sunt parcurse in mod recursiv toate cele n noduri, ceea ce da programului o complexitate medie de O(n).
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="executie problema hide">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          <i class="fas fa-cogs fontawesome-custom"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet is not working properly - if you click on multiple buttons, the text doesn't get updated. (it appears on top of each other)

Comment: I removed too much. Have a look again. I need to test that the div does NOT contain the tgt.dataset.id

Comment: I have a question though - can you explain this line for me - [...document.querySelectorAll("div.problema")]? I didn't ever see those ... before a line. The square brackets cast to an array, so the forEach works I guess. But I don't know about "..."

Comment: It is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). `[...nodeList]` allows array methods on a nodelist - for example older EDGE browsers do not allow forEach on a nodeList

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you are using bootstrap so you can easily use `tabs` it will give you the same behavior of what you are trying to do.
check the following link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior